# JAVA API to rename and delete files in S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, emr

I am implementing PageRanking on Amazon WebServices using Elastic Map Reduce. Following is my Code. The problem is that the rename and delete methods in FileSystem API(Using Hadoop 2.2.0) don't seem to do their job.

Am I missing something?

```
    public class PageRankDriver{
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PageRankDriver.class.toString()); 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    if (args.length != 4||Integer.parseInt(args[3])<0)
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: PageRank <nodes path> <edges path> <output path> <# of iterations> ");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    /*
     * Initial config
     */

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(PageRankDriver.class);

    log.info("Test Debug 1");


    FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]),conf);

    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

    /*
     * Get the number of nodes
     */
    FSDataInputStream nodesFile = fs.open(new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    int count = 0;
    while (nodesFile.readLine() != null)
    {
        count++;
    }
    conf.set("NODE_COUNT", count + "");

    //delete old output folder
    fs.delete(new Path(otherArgs[2]),true);

    conf.setJobName("PageRank");
    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(otherArgs[2]));
    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    conf.setMapperClass(PageRankFirstMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(PageRankFirstReducer.class);
    log.info("----"+TextOutputFormat.getOutputPath(conf).getName());
    conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", false);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setJarByClass(PageRankDriver.class);
    conf.setJar("PageRank.jar");

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    log.info("Test Debug 2");
    //This is used to adjust the path for hdfs or local machine
    String pre="";  
    //||fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString().contains("hadoop");s3://awsee599
    if(fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString().contains("hdfs")||fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString().contains("hadoop"))
    {
        pre="s3://awsee599/";
    }
    /*Path src=new Path(otherArgs[2]+"/part-00000");
    Path dst=new Path(pre);
    fs.copyToLocalFile(src, dst);*/
    boolean test1=fs.rename(new Path(otherArgs[2]+"/part-00000"), new Path(pre+"temp.txt"));
    log.info("Test Debug 3------------"+pre+" Working directory::"+fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString()+" Rename----------"+test1);
    boolean test2=fs.delete(new Path(otherArgs[2]),true);
    log.info("Test Debug 3------------"+pre+" Working directory::"+fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString()+"Delete----"+test2);
    conf.clear();
    boolean test = false;
    /***************************************
     * Now onto the next few iterations
     ***************************************/
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(otherArgs[3]); i++)
    {
        JobConf confNext = new JobConf(PageRankDriver.class);
        log.info("------------FRUIT LOOPS::::"+i);
        //log.info("----"+FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(conf).getName());
        confNext.setJobName("PageRank");
        confNext.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", false);
        confNext.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        confNext.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        log.info("Test debug 4---------------"+fs.getWorkingDirectory().toString());
        //FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(conf);
        if(fs.exists(new Path(otherArgs[2])))
        {
            log.info("--------------------------output exists-----------------------");
            /*fs.delete(new Path(otherArgs[2]),true);*/
        }
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(confNext, new Path(otherArgs[2]));
        log.info("----"+otherArgs[2]);
        if(fs.exists(new Path(pre+"temp.txt")))
        {
            log.info("--------------------------temp.txt exists-----------------------");
        }
        TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(confNext, new Path(pre+"temp.txt"));
        /*FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(confNext, new Path(pre+"temp.txt"));*/


        Path[] path=TextInputFormat.getInputPaths(confNext);
        for (int j = 0; j < path.length; j++) {
            log.info("---------"+path[j].getName()+"------------");
            log.info("------------"+pre+"------------");
        }
        log.info("----"+TextOutputFormat.getOutputPath(confNext).getName());

        confNext.setMapperClass(PageRankSecondMapper.class);
        confNext.setReducerClass(PageRankSecondReducer.class);

        confNext.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        confNext.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
                    /*ERROR PRINTED BELOW is thrown from here*/ 
        RunningJob jb=JobClient.runJob(confNext);
        if(jb.isSuccessful())
            log.info("Yes-------"+jb.getTrackingURL());
        /*fs.setPermission(new Path(pre+"part-00000"), FsPermission.getFileDefault());*/

        test=fs.delete(new Path(pre+"temp.txt"),true);
        log.info("DELETE-temp.txt------------"+test);
        log.info("temp.txt exists----------"+fs.exists(new Path(pre+"temp.txt")));

        log.info(otherArgs[2]+"/part-00000"+"::"+pre+"temp.txt");

        test=fs.rename(new Path(otherArgs[2]+"/part-00000"), new Path(pre+"temp.txt"));
        /*Path src1=new Path(otherArgs[2]+"/part-00000");
        Path dst1=new Path(pre);
        fs.copyToLocalFile(src1, dst1);
        fs.setPermission(new Path(otherArgs[2]), FsPermission.getFileDefault());*/
        fs.delete(new Path(otherArgs[2]),true);
        log.info("After delete and rename;temp.txt exists----------"+fs.exists(new Path(pre+"temp.txt")));
        log.info("After delete and rename;Output exists----------"+fs.exists(new Path(otherArgs[2])));
        confNext.clear();
    }
    log.info("Exiting Main---------------------------");
}
```

}

I get the following exception when I run the above code in EMR. The funny thing is, the For loop runs the first iteration without any fuss.
The same path is accessed in the first run and in the second run the following exception is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3://awsee599/temp.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:905)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java
```